# Parsing Json Data in Android Studio - cannot display all data in logs

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-studio

So basically I am developing an app which retrieves data from mysql database. Therefore I have created a php script which retrieves data from database and outputs  data in JSON format:

```
{
    "newslog": [
        {
            "Id": "1",
            "Title": "News Item 1",
            "Author": "Nich",
            "Body": "aldfjlak dklflksd afkjdflk ",
            "Date": "2016-07-26"
        },
        {
            "Id": "2",
            "Title": "News Item 2",
            "Author": "nich",
            "Body": "la la la la la la",
            "Date": "2016-07-26"
        },
        {
            "Id": "3",
            "Title": "News Item 3",
            "Author": "nich",
            "Body": "oh oh oh oh oh",
            "Date": "2016-07-26"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using Android Studio, and managed to display this data (in JSON format) in Android Studio logs, as shown below:

[image]

**Problem**:

I would like to display parts from this data (JSON) in the logs. However at the moment I can only display in the logs the "Title".  When I try to retrieve the "Id", "Body" or "Date" they seem to be ignored.  I am sure that I am missing something.

**Code used to output data in logs:**

[image: Code used to output data in logs]

**Logs:**

[image]

**Android Studio code:**

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


//       List<String> newsItems = new ArrayList<String>();
//       newsItems.add("News 1");
//       newsItems.add("News 2");
//
//
//      ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newsItems);
//       lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("http://council4u.com/php-scripts/getnews.php");
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {

                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();
                }

                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try{
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(result);

                String latestnews = data.getString("newslog");
               Log.i ("Latest News", latestnews);


                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(latestnews);

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);


                    Log.i("title", jsonPart.getString("Title"));
                    Log.i("Body", jsonPart.getString("Body"));

                }

            }  catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:
you are using :

```
 String latestnews = data.getString("newslog");
```

but in the response it is an array, try to replace those lines :

```
String latestnews = data.getString("newslog");
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(latestnews);
```

By :

```
JSONArray arr = data.getJSONArray("newslog");
```

---

when the message to Log is empty there is no log message, try to log the length of the body and test if it is null :

```
  String body = jsonPart.getString("Body");
  Log.i("title", jsonPart.getString("Title"));
  Log.i("Body", body==null? "null body" : body.length());
```

Comment: I have replaced code as you have proposed but I am still with the same problem... moreover body:null?.... is giving me an error

Comment: ah may be because Log.i() requires a String and `length()` method returns a Integer , try this and comment back the result of Log :

`Log.i("Body", body==null? "null body" : body.length()+"");`

Comment: Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: java.io.serializable', required: 'java.lang.String'

Comment: ok now its not giving me an error (added +" ").  However the "body" still is not being displayed in the logs :/

Comment: is it displaying (null body) or an Integer ? filter the Log with the TAG "Body", please try to log the whole JSONObject to see what it is containing :
  `Log.i("JSON OBJECT", jsonPart.toString());`

Comment: oh  the problem was that in the search i was filtering news.... and obviously body was not being shown

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem trying to log a `Serializable`, `Parcelable` even and `JSON` object getting from `Intent` (or `Extras`) when `onCreate()` inside an `Activity`.

Always show null using `Evaluate Expression` tool... Well, I have try with `Toast` and I have seen that data was right. With `Log` would have the same effect.

Finally, I have assumed that data was correct and problem was on Android Studio debugger.